# Reading HTTPS traffic using a proxy server

Tags: https, proxy, request

**Context**: I have an application which communicates with a server of the owner. This application requests certain information from the server by accessing some URL's. I don't know these URL's, except for a few, but once I know them, I can manually visit them in the browser and obtain said information.

**Goal**: Figuring out the URLs of those requests, i.e., what are the requests being made by the application when I'm using it, so that I can, in the future, make them manually myself.

**Progress**:

- Since the communications are in HTTPS, reading the packets with Wireshark while using the application was unsuccessfull since they are encrypted.
- However, I was able to find where in the binary of the application is the URL of the server located. Thus, I can theoretically redirect the requests of the application to any other server. Hence, I thought a good idea to be able to receive the unencrypted requests would be to set up a proxy server, redirect the application to it, and then execute the application and obtain the results.

**Problem**: I don't know how to implement this idea in practice though, and it is here where I'd appreciate your help. I suppose that, ideally, I would be able to both receive the requests made by the application (and thus read them), as well as redirect them to the server and read the received information.

Comment: This does not work, fortunately. https uses an encryption that is based on a server side key. The client would realize that the transport encryption is not terminated by the originating service, but by your proxy inbetween. You'd have to know the secret keys of the server to be able to sniff the traffic. Which is something you would not do anyway, since it is illegal in most countries, regardless of whether you operate the systems or not.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info, @arkascha. So, even if acting as an intermediate is not possible, is it still possible to at least see the request being sent by the application, by acting as the server? Excuse the inexperience.

Comment: Well, you obviously can see _that_ a request is sent, sure, but not the _contents_ of that request. Reason again is the encryption. Unlike with former `shtml` strategies (1980th...) an https connection does not only encrypt the response, but also the request, so the full communication. Reason for that is obvious, I'd say. What you _can_ see is the requested HTTP_HOST, since that has to be evaluated before the actual termination of the encryption takes place _inside_ that host, but not the encrypted content.